# LaTeX: How to remove specific vertical line between two cells in tabular

Tags: latex, tabular

I am looking for a way to remove the vertical lines between two cells, keeping the vertical lines for the following rows intact. Namely in the example shown below the line before 7.5% and the line after 17.5% without removing the vertical lines defining the box.

This is the result I get from the code I use as stated below:

[image]

I would like to keep the table format so that I can highlight/colorize specific conditions by filling in the corresponding cell. Any suggestions on what I could try?

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}    
\usepackage{float}      % H command
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for cmidrule
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{cc|rcccc|c}
     &  \Block{1-*}{+ 10 $\%$ MPD} \\
     & \Block{1-*}{PEG3350 + PEG1000} \\
     & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \\
      \cmidrule{3-7}
     \Block{3-1}{\rotate NPS salts [mM]} & \small 10 & & & & & & \Block{3-1}{\rotate \small 100 mM bicine/Tris \\ Hcl pH 8.5}\\ 
      & \small 30 & & & & \\
      & \small 50 & & & & \\
      \cmidrule{3-7}
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: What packages do you use? Please, share more of your code (see [MVE] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), to help us to debug your code.

Comment: Have a look at the `tabularray` package, this gives you a lot of control where lines should and shouldn't be

Answer (score 2):

Thank you for the advice on using tabularray, with this package I got the result I was looking for.

[image]

Please find the new code below in case someone else is looking for a similar issue.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{tikz}     % this is for graphics
\usepackage{float}      %this is for H commands
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for PCR command / cmidrule
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{tblr}{
hline{4,Y} = {3-7}{0.75pt},
vline{3,8} = {4-6}{0.75pt},
}
& &\SetCell[c=5]{c} + 10 $\%$ MPD \\
& &\SetCell[c=5]{c} PEG3350 + PEG1000 \\
\SetCell[r=5]{c} \rotatebox{90}{\small NPS salts [mM]} & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \SetCell[r=5]{c, 0.2cm}\rotatebox{90} {\small 100 mM bicine/Tris} & \SetCell[r=5]{c, 0.1cm}\rotatebox{90} {\small Hcl pH 8.5} \\
 & 10 & & & & & &  \\
 & 30 & & & & & &  \\
 & 50 & & & & & &  \\
 & & & & & & & &
\end{tblr}
 \end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The tabularray package is great, isn't it? :) Off-topic: maybe have a look at the siunitx package to get correct spacing between your numbers and the %-signs

Answer (score 1):

With `nicematrix`, the easiest way to draw a rectangle in your tabular is use the command `\Block` with the key `draw` (which draws the frame of the block).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}      % H command
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccrccccc}
     &  \Block{1-*}{+ 10 $\%$ MPD} \\
     & \Block{1-*}{PEG3350 + PEG1000} \\
     & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \\
     \Block{3-1}{\rotate NPS salts [mM]} & \small 10 & \Block[draw]{3-5}{}
     & & & & & \Block{3-1}{\rotate \small 100 mM bicine/Tris \\ Hcl pH 8.5}\\ 
      & \small 30 & & & & \\
      & \small 50 & & & & \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

If you wish rounded corners, use the key `rounded-corners`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}      % H command
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccrccccc}
     &  \Block{1-*}{+ 10 $\%$ MPD} \\
     & \Block{1-*}{PEG3350 + PEG1000} \\
     & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \\
     \Block{3-1}{\rotate NPS salts [mM]} & \small 10 & \Block[draw,rounded-corners]{3-5}{}
     & & & & & \Block{3-1}{\rotate \small 100 mM bicine/Tris \\ Hcl pH 8.5}\\ 
      & \small 30 & & & & \\
      & \small 50 & & & & \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]

If you want to fill it with a background color, use the key `fill`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}      % H command
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccrccccc}
     &  \Block{1-*}{+ 10 $\%$ MPD} \\
     & \Block{1-*}{PEG3350 + PEG1000} \\
     & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \\
     \Block{3-1}{\rotate NPS salts [mM]} & \small 10 & \Block[draw,rounded-corners,fill=red!15]{3-5}{}
     & & & & & \Block{3-1}{\rotate \small 100 mM bicine/Tris \\ Hcl pH 8.5}\\ 
      & \small 30 & & & & \\
      & \small 50 & & & & \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer a gradient of color, it's also possible (thanks to Tikz).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage{float}      % H command
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
 \centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{ccrccccc}
     &  \Block{1-*}{+ 10 $\%$ MPD} \\
     & \Block{1-*}{PEG3350 + PEG1000} \\
     & & \small 7.5 $\%$ & \small 10 $\%$ & \small 12.5 $\%$ & \small 15 $\%$ & \small 17.5 $\%$ & \\
     \Block{3-1}{\rotate NPS salts [mM]} & \small 10 & 
     \Block[draw,rounded-corners,tikz={left color=red!15}]{3-5}{}
     & & & & & \Block{3-1}{\rotate \small 100 mM bicine/Tris \\ Hcl pH 8.5}\\ 
      & \small 30 & & & & \\
      & \small 50 & & & & \\
   \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table} 
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the last code]

Since `nicematrix` creates PGF/Tikz under the rows, cells and columns, it's always possible to draw and fill what you wish...